# Delete some fields

Tags: json, laravel, api

Hi is there a way to remove all rows except "data" which contains datas. Laravel. I want only to be:

```
{
   "data": [],
}
```

How it is now:

```
{
  "current_page": 1,
  "data": [],
  "from": 1,
  "last_page": 1,
  "next_page_url": null,
  "path": "",
  "per_page": 150,
  "prev_page_url": null,
  "to": 14,
  "total": 14
}
```

Comment: `$result->data;`

Comment: Try `$result->items()` or `$result->getItems()` and inform us laravel version.

Answer (score 0):

Yes don't use the `paginate()` functionality and use `get()` instead on your Query/Eloquent. `paginate()` will create all this extra data fields and with `get()` you would only get the data.

Comment: I had to because I have 9 of these. It needs to be separated because they contain different datas. I used get() and got it working but all the datas were shown. When I wanted to have 9 links now it is showing this. Hope I was clear.

Comment: Target the data with `$result->data` or make a loop and interate through `data`. That will do it.